# Java- How can I add a list of objects to another list of Objects

Tags: java, list, object, addition

Scenario: got two lists as following:

```
List<Object[]> listOne = null;
List<Object[]> listTwo = null;
```

aMethod (see at the bottom) is invoked on each lists which returns a compatible type list

```
listOne = aMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3);
listTwo = aMethod(argx, argy, argz);
```

When i try

```
listOne.add(listTwo);
```

I get error about the add function  . Recommends to use addAll(), which i cant use for my reasons. So, any one have idea how to add a list of objects [] to another list of objects []? Thanks.

```
public List<Object[]> aMethod(a1, a2, a3) {
        List<Object[]> aList = service.getSomeinfo();
        return aList;
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear - you want to add all items of the second list to the first list?

Comment: Currently, listOne = aMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3); is part of the code. It is processed as for(Object[] obj : listOne) down the road. Wonder if I use addAll(), will for(Object[] obj : listOne) will work as before?

Comment: Why can't you use addAll() ?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use addAll() method then @Shubbi you can add the second list of object array through the iteration like this :

```
for(Object[] o:listTwo){
    listOne.add(o);
}
```

There is another way and is very efficient also by using Stream Api if you are using Java 8 or upper version

```
listOne = Stream.concat(listOne.stream(), listTwo.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Stream`

```
listOne = Stream.concat(listOne.stream(), listTwo.stream())
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use addAll function of list which adds all the elements of one array to other.

```
listOne.addAll(listTwo);
```

listOne will contain elements from both the lists.
You could add both list to third list as:

```
List<Object[]> listThree = new ArrayList<Object[]>(listOne);
listThree.addAll(listTwo);
```

Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-

Comment: as mentioned above, you can add both listOne and listTwo to listThree. It wont have any effect on other two lists.

Comment: if listOne.addAll(listTwo); then listThree.addAll(listTwo); will not be ncecessory. right?

Comment: @Shubbi The above two are totally 2 different ways of adding OR merging two list. Please dont combine them into a single example.

Comment: First one adds two list in listOne. Second one adds both the list in listThree. Select either first or second